# Obtener dirección IP externa en Android

Tags: java, android, json, webservice

¿Existe alguna función en Java de Android, que devuelve la dirección IP externa, en caso de tener conectividad y salida a Internet?

Mi idea es crear una función `getPublicIPAddress()` y que haga una petición simple a uno de la lista y devuelve la IP en formato cadena.

Lista de algunos servidores que devuelve la IP:

- [icfg](https://ifcfg.me/ip)
- [amazonaws](http://checkip.amazonaws.com/)
- [akamai](http://whatismyip.akamai.com/)
- [icanhazip](http://icanhazip.com/)
- [trackip](http://www.trackip.net/ip)
- [myexternalip](http://myexternalip.com/raw)
- [ipecho](http://ipecho.net/plain)

Iré añadiendo el código en una respuesta...

Comment: He encontrado otro pero da info de GeoIP http://freegeoip.net/json/ y más precisión en geoIP http://www.ip2location.com/

Answer (score 2):

Usando como referencia la url http://ip.jsontest.com/ que devuelve la ip en formato **JSON**.

En ***OnCreate***:

```
     //En el botón hacemos el llamado de la función asíncrona GetTextViewData

     txtIP= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtviewIp);
     mostrarIp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mostrarMiIp);


mostrarIp .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                new GetTextViewData(context).execute();

            }
        });
```

Creamos la función para obtener el json desde la Url.

```
 private class GetTextViewData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        public Context context;


        public GetTextViewData(Context context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0)
        {

            HttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost myConnection = new HttpPost("http://ip.jsontest.com/");

            try {
                response = myClient.execute(myConnection);
                str = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), "UTF-8");

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            try{
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(str);
                json = jArray.getJSONObject(0);



            } catch ( JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            try {
                String txtIp= json.getString("ip");

                //Obtenemos el texto y lo pasamos al textview
                MyIp.setText(txtIp);

             Log.e(TAG, "ip" + json.getString("ip"));


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Con esa función se puede obtener la dirección IP Publica.

```
public static String getPublicIPAddress(Context context) {

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    final NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    RunnableFuture<String> futureRun = new FutureTask<>(new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() throws Exception {
            if ((info != null && info.isAvailable()) && (info.isConnected())) {
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                try {
                    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (
                            new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com/").openConnection());
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Android-device");
                    //urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    urlConnection.setReadTimeout(15000);
                    urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/json");
                    urlConnection.connect();

                    int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

                    if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(line);
                        }

                    }
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                    return response.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                //Log.w(TAG, "No network available INTERNET OFF!");
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
    });

    new Thread(futureRun).start();

    try {
        return futureRun.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

**Su uso**
Su uso es muy simple solo se debe pasar el contexto y devuelve la dirección IP publica.

```
String publicIPAddress = getPublicIPAddress(this); //devuelve la dirección ip
```